# "Fake" collision that can be detected by RaySensor but doesnt collide with other models?

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to implement some kind of particle system to generate sensor data that look like the sensor is in a smoky or fogy environment. So i implemented a plugin to spawn one model with 3000 tiny collision boxes with random location's. The data's look good so far, I'm planning to move the collision boxes that it look's like real noise jitter.

The Problem is that the "smoke" model also collides with other models. Is there a way to get rid of that?

I know that there are probably more efficient ways to implement this and in the next month i will spend some time on this problem. If someone could give me some hint's i will start to work on that.

[image: Particle_laserSensor_visualization]

Greetings Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19825/%22fake%22-collision-that-can-be-detected-by-raysensor-but-doesnt-collide-with-other-models?/) by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 350 on 2018-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you use a GPU ray sensor, you can remove collisions from your particles, because the sensor only detects the visuals.

If you use a (CPU) ray sensor, you can try playing with [collision bitmasks](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=collide_bitmask&cat=physics).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-06-26**:
Thanks, i think this will be a sufficient solution for my task.

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-06-28**:
One more "tiny" question. Does it make a difference which driver runs on my graphic card?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-28**:
It may make a difference for the GPU sensor, not for the CPU one.

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-06-30**:
Thank's a lot for the fast answers.